# Modify a layout-circle for turtles in NetLogo

Tags: layout, netlogo

I am trying to get a `layout-circle`in NetLogo to have every second turtle to move one coordinate towards the centre, and the remaining ones to move away from it. I have found a way around using `random`, but the result is not really tidy. What I am trying to get is turtles that are positioned in a zig-zag manner around the circle, without the random component I am getting. For instance, that all even-numbered turtles move towards the centre, and all odd-numbered ones move away.

Any thoughts, hoping this is sufficiently clear?

```
to setup
  clear-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  layout-circle (sort turtles) max-pxcor - 1
  ask turtles [setxy xcor (ycor + random 3 - 1)]
end
```

[image: Output of the above code in NetLogo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your turtles are sorted, using their `who` would work. Also, if you want to preserve the circle layout, you should have turtles move along the radius rather than according to the world's coordinates (and surely get rid of `random` if you want no random effects).

Before we proceed, a big **warning**: you will read quite regularly that using agents' `who` is bad NetLogo coding practice (I myself still need to understand exactly why that is dangerous).
Considering that your turtles are sorted in the layout and assuming this passage happens just upon setup, I think it is sufficiently safe to use `who` in your case - however, I also include an approach that doesn't use `who`, which would also be needed in case of unsorted turtles.

In both cases, the outcome is this:

[image]

(note that this perfect zigzag is possible only if turtles are created in an even number)

### Approach with `who`

```
to setup
  clear-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  layout-circle (sort turtles) max-pxcor - 1

  ask turtles [
    ifelse (who mod 2 = 0)
      [forward 0.5]
      [forward -0.5]
  ]
end
```

By doing this, every even turtle will move forwards by a bit, and every odd turtle will move backwards by the same amount.

### Approach without `who`

This has to be more elaborated.

We take advantage of the fact that, if we make turtles move alternately forwards and backwards (achieved by `ifelse (counter mod 2 = 0) [] []`) from the circle layout, then the closest turtle to the last moving turtle (the moving turtle is `reference-turtle` in the code) will be the next turtle on the circle perimeter who hasn't moved yet.

At the end of every `while` iteration, the current `reference-turtle` will ask the closest turtle to become the new `reference-turtle`.

To make this all work, we can use `counter` both as the stop condition for the `while` loop and as the condition based on which turtles know whether to move forwards or backwards

```
to setup
  clear-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  layout-circle turtles max-pxcor - 1

  let counter 0
  let reference-turtle one-of turtles
  
  while [counter < count turtles] [
    ask reference-turtle [
      ifelse (counter mod 2 = 0)
        [forward 0.5]
        [forward -0.5]
      
      ask min-one-of other turtles [distance myself] [
        set reference-turtle self
      ]
    ]
    
    set counter counter + 1
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matteo, both are marvellows answers ane the use of `mod` solves the issue spot-on. Thanks for the info non-`who` option too, I'll keep it as I may need to include position shifts outisde of `setup`